# Why is "permission denied" always in samba share?

Tags: samba, ubuntu-22.04

On Ubuntu 22.04 created a share, but it not working, Permission denied.

Samba log:

```
[2023/07/20 11:31:53.762349,  0] ../../source3/smbd/service.c:168(chdir_current_service)
  chdir_current_service: vfs_ChDir(/home/nlrp/fivem) failed: Permission denied. Current token: uid=1002, gid=1002, 2 groups: 1002 1003
```

Samba share:

```
[fivem-prod]
comment = Samba FiveM-prod
path = /home/nlrp/fivem
read only = no
writable = yes
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
valid users = @smb_hozzaferes
create mask = 0775
directory mask = 0775
```

"smb_hozzaferes" group:

```
root@gameserver:/home/nlrp# getent group smb_hozzaferes
smb_hozzaferes:x:1003:spici_smb,smoker_smb
```

Directory permissions:

```
drwxrwsr-x+ 5 nlrp smb_hozzaferes 4096 Jul 12 18:52 /home/nlrp/fivem
```

```
root@gameserver:/home/nlrp# namei -om /home/nlrp/fivem
f: /home/nlrp/fivem
 drwxr-xr-x root root           /
 drwxr-xr-x root root           home
 drwxr-x--- nlrp nlrp           nlrp
 drwxrwsr-x nlrp smb_hozzaferes fivem
```

"spici_smb" have "smbpasswd"

Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks